# What should I look for when choosing faux tin ceiling tiles?

Tags: ceiling

My fiancee really likes the look of the faux tin ceilings. We found some in Home Depot, but they are 20$ for each 18" x 24" pane. For a moderate sized room, this will be a LOT of money to do one ceiling! (I'm assuming they're so expensive because they are "thermoplastic" rated to be resistant to up to 200 degrees or something like that; I guess this is because they are also for use as splashguards behind the stove.)

So I figured I'd look online for other possibilities, but there are a LOT of different brands and suppliers. What should I look for (and stay away from) when choosing faux tin ceiling tiles?

Comment: I think they're expensive because they're not used often (it's a supply and demand thing). They seem to mainly be used in higher end homes and/or remodels of older homes (where tin ceilings were more common), so it's not a product the average homeowner would use.

Comment: Hmm, I've found at a local paneling place that you can get the plastic tiles, unfinished and ready for painting, for about 3.xx$/sq-ft, as opposed to Home Depot's 6.67$/sq-ft. Little extra work to paint them, but a BIG savings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a while I came across TinCeilingXpress.com They offered a 5 panel sample package which allowed me to pick 5 tiles to see what I liked best. They are reasonably priced and I found they were quick at shipping and the products came well packaged. At ~$7.00 a tile I ended up buying [these tiles](http://www.tinceilingxpress.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_77&products_id=72):

[image]

I have been pleased with how easy they were to put up and how great it looks. My biggest gripe is how sharp the tiles are. I would highly recommend some gloves when installing.

Best of luck!

Comment: Wow! At $ 1.75 a sq foot, that's the cheapest I've seen them, too. How long ago was it that you installed these? Have they been holding up well?

Comment: They've been in place for about a month. They are not going anywhere! The tiles are actually real steel and were easy to put in place. As I mentioned the worst part of the job was cutting the tiles with tin snips. Made for super sharp edges.

Comment: Very cool... will definitely have to check them out! Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Talked to the company, something to note on these tiles is they are plain steel, not stainless, so steps may be necessary to account for rust. Still going to check them out though!

Comment: The company did have the choice of different finishes at -- additional cost. I enjoyed the steel look so I ended up using a polyurethane on the tiles to help with rust. No sign of rust in the month they have been up.  They are inside the house with heat and air conditioning, so I think I'll be ok.

Comment: How'd you do that? Was it the same kind of polyurethane that you would use on say, a wooden floor?

Comment: Indeed, I used the following where I purchased it at my local Home Depot. http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100136801/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=polyurethane&storeId=10051
It's oil based, so I believe I should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

I gather first, that you are looking at [FRP](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbqk5/h_d2/Navigation?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) (Fiberglass Reinforced Paneling) as opposed to [Faux Ceiling Tiles](http://www.homedepot.com/Building-Materials-Ceilings-Attics-Ceilings-Grid-Ceilings/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbnes/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&Nu=P_PARENT_ID&langId=-1&storeId=10051&searchNav=true) based on your statement that ".*..they are "thermoplastic" rated to be resistant to up to 200 degrees or something like that; I guess this is because they are also for use as splashguards behind the stove.*"  FRP panels, which usually come in 4x8 sheets, are the much less expensive option; however, they do not offer a fraction of the design and style opportunities.  I've created ceilings with both, and would recommend that if you are looking for a textural design, without the cost, that you forget about both and consider making yourself a cutout template and instead design a pattern that makes you both happy.  You can then use this [Texturing Plaster](http://howto.homedepot.com/videos/watch/909857737001/Texturing-Plaster-Walls.html) instructional How-To that was designed for walls, but works just as well on ceilings.